# Libre Barcode 39 Font doesn't appear on mobile device email client

Tags: html, css, email, fonts, webfonts

I have an Email written in html containing the following

CSS:

```
@font-face {
            font-family: 'Libre Barcode 39';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-display: auto;
            src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/librebarcode39/v19/-nFnOHM08vwC6h8Li1eQnP_AHzI2G_Bx0g.woff2) format('woff2');
            unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+0304, U+0308, U+0329, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
        }

.barcode {
            font-family: 'Libre Barcode 39' !important;
            font-size: 5em;
            color: #000;
        }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="prizeWin barcode">
                *#BarCode*
</div>
```

Where #BarCode is aimed to be replaced by the actual code.

When I receive the Email on gmail I have this on desktop :
[Received Email on Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZp3R.png)

and this on mobile:
[Received Email on Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzGTq.jpg)(same source)

Not sure how to get around the restriction about web Fonts on Mobile.

I tried using other google fonts but the same result occured.

Comment: A lot of email clients either ignore css features like `@font-face` or download them on-demand (e.g showing a button like "load images/assets"). (see [canimail](https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=%40font-face)) . You might opt for a server-side generated png. E.g. using a php function like [`imagettftext()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php)

Comment: @herrstrietzel would love to genereate the image serverSide but I'm supposed to have 50000 of them wich would weight a lot on the server and not be super efficient. thanks regardless

Comment: You could add a simple caching condition (if ean doesn't exist - write it to server) or just create all images in a batch.